# How to check if a property exists in Settings?

Tags: c#, settings

I used to define properties of Settings at design time in Visual Studio, but I wanted to add properties at runtime. I searched Google, and found a way like this,

```
        var s = Properties.Settings.Default;
        var property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("x")
        {
            DefaultValue = -1,
            IsReadOnly=false,
            PropertyType=typeof(int),
            Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"],
        };
        property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
```

The problem is, how do I know if that property exists or not? There will not be that property before adding it at runtime. I tried to find a Contains() method, but there was no such method, and doing the code below did not work because it did not just return null but caused an exception.

```
        var s = Properties.Settings.Default;
        var x = s["x"];
        if (x != null)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties is the collection of `SettingsProperty`, so when you cast it correctly, you can make a LINQ requests over the typed collection. The rest is quite easy:

```
  var exists = s.Properties.OfType<SettingsProperty>().Any(p => p.Name == "x");
```